# How to install odoo 8 on ubuntu 20.04

Tags: odoo-8, ubuntu-20.04

I tried to install odoo 8 on vps ubuntu 20.04 but i have this type of error

odoo : Depends: python-feedparser but it is not installable

```
    Depends: python-imaging but it is not installable

    Depends: python-ldap but it is not installable

    Depends: python-libxslt1 but it is not installable

    Depends: python-openid but it is not installable

    Depends: python-psycopg2 but it is not installable

    Depends: python-pychart but it is not installable

    Depends: python-pydot but it is not installable

    Depends: python-pypdf but it is not installable

    Depends: python-reportlab but it is not installable

    Depends: python-requests but it is not installable

    Depends: python-vatnumber but it is not installable

    Depends: python-vobject but it is not installable

    Depends: python-werkzeug but it is not installable

    Depends: python-xlwt but it is not installable

    Recommends: antiword but it is not going to be installed

    Recommends: graphviz

    Recommends: ghostscript

    Recommends: python-gevent but it is not installable

    Recommends: poppler-utils
```

How can i install odoo 8 on ubuntu 20.04

Comment: Try [GreenOdoo](https://github.com/buke/GreenOdoo/tree/8.0-linux64), you only need to clone the Linux branch

Comment: Hi @Kenly Thanks, when i tried to run start.sh i have some permission troubles if you can help me, i tried to give all permission to runtime folder but i still have the problems